# How to get CPU Utilization report, thread and cores analysis in VS 2017 profiler?

Tags: visual-studio, profiler

In the book I found examples of CPU utilazatition report, thread and core analysis tabs. It should be in Debug - Start Performance Analysis - Concurrency.  Here is screenshot of what I need:
 [image]

But in my VS2017 Enterprise I couldn't find them in Debug - Performance Profiler - Performance Wizard neither in Resource contention data (concurrency) nor in CPU Sampling.
Here is screenshot of what I get:
 [image]

Comment: For earlier versions of VS the Concurrency Visualizer should be installed as a VS [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ConcurrencyVisualizerforVisualStudio2015#overview). Not sure whether anything changed for VS 2017.

Comment: We have just published a new version of Concurrency Visualizer for VS 2017. Let me know if you have any issues https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.ConcurrencyVisualizer2017#qna